# Assignment in .loc loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','2'], ['3', '4']])
```

If we look at dtypes, all the numbers are objects:

```
df.dtypes
0    object
1    object
```

I want to have them as int or float. So if I do

```
df_apply = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

I get

```
df_apply.dtypes
0    int64
1    int64
dtype: object
```

Same if I do

```
df_astype_int = df.astype(int)
df_astype_int.dtypes
0    int64
1    int64
```

Or

```
df_astype_float = df.astype(float)
df_astype_float.dtypes
0    float64
1    float64
dtype: object
```

Or

```
df_loop = df.copy()
for i in df_loop:
    df_loop[i] = pd.to_numeric(df_loop[i])    
df_loop.dtypes
0    int64
1    int64
```

But if I do

```
df_loop = df.copy()
for index in df_loop.index:
    df_loop.loc[index,:] = pd.to_numeric(df_loop.loc[index,:])
df_loop.dtypes
0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

I get objects again. Why is that? It doesn't raise any errors, but doesn't convert either.

Comment: It gives me `int64` tho... I can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: 1.1.5. Just tested with down to 1.0.0, same. BUT works on python2

Comment: * python2 / pandas 0.24.2

Answer (score 1):

In the below:

```
for index in df_loop.index:
    df_loop.loc[index,:] = pd.to_numeric(df_loop.loc[index,:])
```

You are trying to assign a row of `Series` with dtype `int`. The result got upcasted to `object` which is the common NumPy dtype of all types column-wise, since `pandas` is column based. For added info, see [numpy.find_common_type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.find_common_type.html).

But when you convert the dtype of the whole DataFrame or a column, it would work fine just like the other samples you provided.

Comment: Thanks. They must have changed the rows / Series processing with pandas 1.0.0